# How to create a user in ActiveMQ Artemis?

Tags: java, jmx, activemq-artemis

I don't understand how to create user with password in ActiveMQ Artemis

Here is my artemis-roles.properties:

```
amq = admin
test = admin
```

Here is my artemis-users.properties:

```
admin = ENC(1024:28CE6B0C9D3FA57ECD8956D429030E5414B730FEEA285A7C8DFEBA434296674C:7946CE5918E1AA81D7D40345F1D348E2293DECBD39F15C45A8E7A308F3C54B128B20B499F6A9A0876BFA834C9E28FBA3076ECB69976031CFC9BDE71B5D0F8B13)
```

I don't understand how to create a user with login - test and password too - test. This user with the role will be used to connect via JMX

Comment: Any feedback here? Were you able to create a user?

Comment: User successfully created, thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to create a user with the default properties files is to the use the suite of "user" commands offered by the Artemis CLI, e.g.:

```
./artemis user add --user-command-user admin --user-command-password adminPassword --role test
```

This is discussed further in [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/security.html#propertiesloginmodule). You can also run the `./artemis help user` command to get details on all the different "user" commands and their options.

Of course, you can also edit the files manually as well. The syntax of the `artemis-roles.properties` file is:

```
<role> = <listOfUsers>
```

The `listOfUsers` could be a single user or a comma-separated list of users in that role.

The syntax of the `artemis-users.properties` file is:

```
<user> = <password>
```